# NameError: name 'final_error_code' is not defined

Tags: python

I tried to assign final_error_code as a global variable but still the problem persists.

File "C:\Ujjwal\sample_python_proj - Copy\fetch_array.py", line 154, in get_error_code_array
print("Lemon Squeeze", final_error_code)
NameError: name 'final_error_code' is not defined

---

```
def get_error_code_array():
    array_pt_failed_current = []
    # global final_error_code
    for loop in files:
        # print("This is get error code first loop", loop)
        with open(loop, 'w+') as file:
            # print("This is get error code second loop", loop)
            lines = file.readlines()
            error_str = json.dumps(lines)
            print("This is get error code of ",error_str)
            for pt_found in re.finditer('PT-', error_str):
                i = pt_found.end() + 1
                pt_failed_current = error_str[pt_found.end()] + error_str[i] + error_str[i+1]
                array_pt_failed_current.append(pt_failed_current)
                final_error_code = ["PT-"+ls for ls in array_pt_failed_current]
                # show_error_code_array.append(final_error_code)
    print("Lemon Squeeze", final_error_code)
    return (final_error_code)
```

Comment: Initialize `final_error_code` before the first loop as an empty list, in the case that e.g. `files` is empty or `re.finditer` is empty.

Answer (score 3):

`final_error_code` is defined in your loop.

If it is not defined, that means that your loop didn't loop at all.

Your `for` loop condition is: `re.finditer('PT-', error_str)`, so I assume that `re.finditer(...)` didn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, I think lines = file.readlines() is returning an empty array. It should enter something else.